# Unable to diagnose why Azure APIM fails to log to Event Hub

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-eventhub

We've an Azure based solution that tracks user actions on a SharePoint web site. A SharePoint extension produces a JSON payload that is sent to an **API Management** resource with the task to log it to **Event Hub**.

Useless I describe next parts of the architecture since will go beyond the purpose of the question.

We're used to deploy the whole solution automating DevOps with a custom software.

In the last deploy the APIM seems unable to work properly. The request took about 3 minutes and ends with `502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server`.
I get this error using postman where it should normally return a mocked 200 after logging to Event Hub.

This is the XML policy used:

```xml
<set-body>@{
                var body = context.Request.Body.As<JObject>(); 
                body.Add(new JProperty("event_id", Guid.NewGuid().ToString()));
                body.Add(new JProperty("ip_address", context.Request.IpAddress));
                body.Add(new JProperty("ingest_status", "unknown"));
                return body.ToString(); 
            }</set-body>
<log-to-eventhub logger-id="pagesLogger">@(
                context.Request.Body.As<string>(preserveContent: true)
            )</log-to-eventhub>
<mock-response status-code="200" content-type="application/json" />
```

This is the top-level **ALL APIs** policy:

```xml
<cors>
    <allowed-origins>
        <origin>*</origin>
    </allowed-origins>
    <allowed-methods>
        <method>GET</method>
        <method>POST</method>
        <method>OPTIONS</method>
    </allowed-methods>
    <allowed-headers>
        <header>*</header>
    </allowed-headers>
</cors>
```

The weird thing is that also commenting `log-to-eventhub` I get an error response: `500 - The request timed out`.

I tried to create another API in the same APIM resource but I'm still unable to get a 200 from a mocked response. Also creating a brand new APIM resource it's not able to solve the problem.

Enabling application insights on APIM did not help to get further informations. The same also with Event Hub diagnostics.

I don't expect a solution but I would really appreciate hints that help me diagnose the problem.

Comment: Maybe it's a DNS issue. Are you using VNET integration, custom DNS server,...?

Comment: Nope man, none of these

Answer (score 0):

It was an Azure issue. Without changing anything after two days everything
is back to normality